# NiFI :- Failed to create Extension Definition for CONTROLLER_SERVICE org.apache.nifi.record.sink.lookup.RecordSinkServiceLookup

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi

I'm trying to use DBCPConnectionPool service in my custom processor. So, how to use in-built controller services (which are already available on NiFi) in our custom processors.

Here are my properties in *-nar/->pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sample.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-customprocessor-processors</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
            <type>nar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here are my dependencies in *processors/->pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-mock</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-dbcp-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-dbcp-service-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And here is my propertydescriptor for DBCPConnetionPool service :-

```
public static final PropertyDescriptor DBCPConnectionPool_SERVICE = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("DBCPConnectionPoolLookup Service")
            .description("The Controller Service to use in order to establish a connection")
            .required(true)
            .dynamic(true)
            .identifiesControllerService(DBCPService.class)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
            .build();
```

and in my OnTrigger method I didn't used it as :-

```
DBCPService DBCPService = context.getProperty(DBCPConnectionPool_SERVICE)
                .asControllerService(DBCPService.class);

Connection con = DBCPService.getConnection();
```

and was trying to use this con object as in regular passion createStatement->executeQuery.

When I tried to package it using `mvn clean install` it started throwing error as **: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.nifi:nifi-nar-maven-plugi
n:1.3.1:nar: org/apache/nifi/record/sink/RecordSinkService**
then I added the following dependencies in processors/->pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-record-sink-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-record-sink-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This time it was new error as :- **Failed to create Extension Definition for CONTROLLER_SERVICE org.apache.nifi.record.sink.lookup.RecordSinkServiceLookup: Null
PointerException**

I also checked by commenting out code which I have written, to check the way I'm using that property was wrong but, even that didn't worked.:-

```
DBCPService DBCPService = context.getProperty(DBCPConnectionPool_SERVICE)
                .asControllerService(DBCPService.class);

Connection con = DBCPService.getConnection();
```

Can someone help me out in order to use DBCPConnectionPoolService controller service in my custom processor?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues the other day and I solved it by using  `AbstractControllerService` instead of `DBCPConnectionPool` therefore not needing `org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService` anymore. Therefore my code would look like this:

```
MyService DBCPService = context.getProperty(DBCPConnectionPool_SERVICE)
                .asControllerService(MyService.class);

Connection con = DBCPService.getConnection();
```

MyService is the custom interface that extends ControllerService.(you have to use it when you also define the `PropertyDescriptor DBCPConnectionPool_SERVICE`)

And `StandardMyService` the class that extends `AbstractControllerService` and implements `MyService` and `getConnection()` from it.